# Probability to score marks

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

An examination consists of 8 questions in each of which the candidate must say which one of the 5 alternatives is correct one . Assuming that the student has not prepared earler chooses for each of the question any one of the 5 answers
 .

What is the probability that he gets correct answer to six or more question .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use **Binomial Distribution** here. The formula that finds the probabilities for the binomial distribution for probability of success $p$, fixed number of trials $n$, and $k$ successes is as follows: $$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$ Here $p$ stands for the probability of a correct answer and obviously $(1-p)$ for that of a wrong answer. Let $X$ denote the variable to represent the number of total correct answers in the quiz. We need to calculate $P(X=6)+P(X=7)+P(X=8)$. Using $p=0.20$ as there is equal probability of choosing any of the five options. Using the distribution formula, we get, $$P_{req} = \binom{8}{6}(0.20)^6(0.80)^2 + \binom{8}{7}(0.20)^7(0.80)^1 + \binom{8}{8}(0.20)^8(0.80)^0 = 0.00123136.$$ Hope it helps.